# VLAN's between DELL 3548 and DELL 6248 (not using trunk)

Tags: vlan, dell

I have a 6248 switch on one floor connected to 3 other floors in the building, all seems to be working but on one floor I would like to have a separate VLAN for a WIFI Access Point, and also boardroom access etc.

I was going to post pictures but don't have enough reputation yet, I am using the GUI to setup.  Basically under VLAN Membership on both switches I have create a VLAN called WIFI using VLAN ID of 4 on both, all the ports in the WIFI VLAN show U.

There 2 separate cables between the floor and I want the traffic to remain separate so I don't want to use trunking.

I assumed if I kept it all separate the VLAN setup should be straight forward but the traffic will not flow between the two switches, if I replace the 3548 with a non-managed switch it all works.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't have a VLAN that spans two or more switches without trunking the switches.

An unmanaged switch works because it sends all traffic between the switches, regardless of the VLAN, which means that all of the traffic on the unmanaged switch is co-mingled, again regardless of VLAN.

The VLAN traffic is already "separated" by virtue of being in separate VLAN's, which is the entire point of using VLAN's. I'm not really understanding what you're trying to achieve with your current set up.

Comment: I have a cable for each VLAN between the two switches so would it not only be sending all the traffic over those cables regardless, a similar question was posted here [link]http://serverfault.com/questions/403458/how-to-interconnect-2-switches-cisco-dell-with-trunks?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You're missing that your switches are all VLAN aware and thus throw away packets that have VLAN tags that are not set up.

Comment: I figured since I was using a separate cable between the switches for each VLAN all the traffic for that VLAN would pass through and then go to all the ports on the other switch.  At what point is this failing? On the 6248 I have a router handing out IP's and I can connect a device to another of the VLAN ports on the 6248 and it gets an IP, but not on a corresponding VLAN port on the 3548.  So are you saying that even though they are connected via separate cable, that when the 6248 sends a packet upstairs it is not tagged properly so the 3548, just ignores?